# Popovers in Storyboard, how to handle the delegate

Tags: swift, delegates, storyboard

In a storyboard i have a view controller which has a segue to another viewcontroller, with the "Present As Popover" applied. If i don't add any code, this works as id expect.

Issue:
I need to get the delegate working so i can get data back from the popover. I have created the delegate in the popover.

I have added

```
class LoginView: UIViewController,UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate,KeypadDelegate
```

I have added the functions to my main view controller.

Issue i have is how to set the delegate on the segue.

i have tried

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "KeyPadLoad"
        {
            let popoverViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! UIViewController
            popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
            popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
        }
    }
```

The segue is defiantly called KeyPadLoad but when the delegate functions should be called in the popover nothing happens.

What am i doing wrong

Thanks

Comment: Also, check this answer by @valosip https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60677831/delegation-to-pass-data-back-from-modally-presented-view-controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to implement the `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` in the class that presents the Popover. The methods of the `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` protocol let you customize the behavior of a popover-based presentation.

If you have set a segue to go to the Popover and you set the segue as `Present as Popover` then your class has to be like this :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

       var popOver = segue.destinationViewController as! PopOverViewController
       popOver.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self        
   }

   // Tells the delegate that the popover was dismissed.  
   func popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {
       println("dismissed")
   }
}
```

Where the class `PopOverViewController` is just an `UIViewController` that handle the Popover, no more, something like this code :

```
class PopOverViewController: UIViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }
 }
```

With the above code you should see the message:

```
dismissed
```

Every time that the `PopOverViewController` is dismissed.

I hope this help you.

Comment: popOver.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self        
didn't work however if i changed it to popOver.delegate=self then it worked as id expect. thanks